# boost asio service queue deepness and policies

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I understand a running asio service is like a queue I can use to post tasks a thread will execute sequentially. However, as any queue, I guess there are limits. Is it possible to set this limit for asio services? Is it possible to set what policy to follow when the queue is full (i.e. blocking, non blocking, etc.)?

**UPDATE**

Suppose I have a thread running an asio::service and a timer posting each 10ms a task to this thread. The task reception is bound to a method invokation which will make the thread sleeping for 100ms. I have therefore a timer posting 100 tasks a second to a thread which is capable of performing 10 tasks each second. It is evident that this situation will diverge. However, when dealing with queues, there are usually means to dimension the queue deepness (100? 1000? posts enqueued, etc.) or to specify the policy a sender should follow when the queue is full (i.e. shall it wait or shall it drop the request and continue?). My question is Ho to set these features in asio::service?

Comment: this question is a tad vague, perhaps you could clarify with an example?

Comment: thank for your comment Sam. I hope it is easier to understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asio does not provide policies to control the internal data structures.  However, it does provide hooks into handler allocations: [`asio_handler_allocate`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_allocate.html) and [`asio_handler_deallocate`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_deallocate.html).  These hooks can be used by an application to limit the amount of outstanding asynchronous operations, as well as defining the behavior when the user specified limit is reached.

There are a few key points to consider:

- `asio_handler_allocate` is expected to return a valid memory block or throw an exception.  If an exception is thrown from `asio_handler_allocate`, it will continue unwinding the stack through calls like [`io_service::post()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html).  Thus, for a non-blocking behavior when the max is reached, throwing may be the only option.
- Consider the effects on composed operations, such as [`async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html), where `asio_handler_allocate` and `asio_handler_deallocate` may be called multiple times.  If an exception is thrown, a thread's stack will unwind to at least the point at which `io_service::run` was invoked.  If blocking occurs, then it could be possible to have all threads servicing the reactor to become blocked, essentially preventing all asynchronous jobs from completing.

Here is an allocation [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/allocation/server.cpp) from the Boost.Asio examples showing a memory-pool being used for handlers.

Answer (score 2):

There is none that I am aware of. As for your example, you are much better off having a timer in the `io_service`'s thread that performs a long running task and re-schedules itself once the work is done. Otherwise you will never clean-up your queue. And if you want a real-time system with good timing constraints — neither a generic OS/programming nor boost.asio is up for a task.

Comment: Queue management is relevant in any multi-threading application, not just RT

Comment: @Silli: It is. But if you fire more often than you can handle, constantly, then it is not going to work. Checking the queue is not needed in your case — you have to place the timer on the same queue and re-schedule it upon completion of the previous task.

Comment: it was (obviously), an example. I am wondering about unpredictable conditions in which I could not estimate how much time it will take to perform a task (for instance..)

Comment: Oh, boy. ASIO got no idea as to how to handle back-pressure from producers. But nobody prevents you from keeping a counter yourself. Just increment it on post, decrement on completion. You can also measure latency by enqueueing a timestamp and checking it on completion if you need. I just don't see how Asio is supposed to solve this problem generically.